# Lotus notes give an error message during calling Crystal Report viewer control 9

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, lotus-notes

OS : window 7 Enterprise Service pack 1 (32 bit)
Lotus notes version : 9.0 (social edition)

Whenever i want to create an object- crystal report viewer control 9 it give me an error message: below is error message that generate by lotus notes

[image]

-Already register odbc driver for lotus notes 9.0

May i know how to fix this error?

Here is the fatal stack.

```
############################################################
### FATAL THREAD 1/12 [ NLNOTES:  10e0:  10e4]
### FP=0x001b8208, PC=0x0887e890, SP=0x001b81c4
### stkbase=001c0000, total stksize=241664, used stksize=32316
### EAX=0x080ebf23, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x001b8188, EDX=0x77af70f4
### ESI=0x0887e890, EDI=0x001e071e, CS=0x0000001b, SS=0x00000023
### DS=0x00000023, ES=0x00000023, FS=0x0000003b, GS=0x00000000 Flags=0x00010206
Exception code: c0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)
############################################################
 [ 1] 0x77525f9f USER32.SetPropW+474 (0,80ebf23,1e071e,81)
 [ 2] 0x77524f0e USER32.GetScrollBarInfo+253 (140a4b0,81,0,1b834c)
 [ 3] 0x7751e98a USER32.SendMessageTimeoutW+1329 (1b8324,60,1b87e0,77af6fe0)
 [ 4] 0x77af702e ntdll.KiUserCallbackDispatcher+46 (0,c2d0,0,56000000)
 [ 5] 0x7751ec54 USER32.SendMessageTimeoutW+2043 (0,c2d0,0,56000000)
 [ 6] 0x7751ecaf USER32.CreateWindowExW+51 (0,c2d0,0,56000000)
 [ 7] 0x080ebfd0 crviewer9 (190534,1b87b8,0,56000000)
 [ 8] 0x080fd319 crviewer9.DllUnregisterServer+6942 (fffffffc,1b8838,80fdcc8,1b8838)
 [ 9] 0x080fedb5 crviewer9.DllUnregisterServer+13754 (887e8c0,fffffffc,0,83658d8)
@[10] 0x5a8d6076 nnotesws.CEditorOLEContainedObj::DoVerb+454 (23053c,fffffffc,0,508)
@[11] 0x59f7a777 nnotesws.DocOLEActivateInPlaceWhenVisible@4+439 (8b3c7a8)
@[12] 0x59f3f94e nnotesws.DocOLEAsyncEvent@12+846 (8335018,508,0)
@[13] 0x59edf24b nnotesws.@DocWindowsMessage@24+19531 (508,0,1b8c7c,1b9120,0,0)
@[14] 0x59ee4699 nnotesws.EditInstanceMessage@24+1161 (8335018,23053c,4f8,508,0,0)
@[15] 0x59ee38a3 nnotesws.CEditSubprogram::SubMessageProc+323 (8352418,4f8,508,0,0,0)
@[16] 0x59eb515d nnotesws.MainWndProc@16+8685 (23053c,4f8,508,0)
 [17] 0x7752c4e7 USER32.gapfnScSendMessage+463 (59eb2f70,23053c,4f8,508)
 [18] 0x7752c5e7 USER32.gapfnScSendMessage+719 (0,59eb2f70,23053c,4f8)
 [19] 0x7752cc19 USER32.gapfnScSendMessage+2305 (59eb2f70,0,1b9274,59f50b3a)
 [20] 0x7752cc70 USER32.DispatchMessageW+15 (1b9250,775253ba,601ba,59eb0000)
@[21] 0x59f50b3a nnotesws.NEMMainLoop@4+1194 (10f13b0)
@[22] 0x010f1f80 NLNOTES.WinMain@16+3024 (10f0000,0,1,0)
@[23] 0x010f2f95 NLNOTES.__tmainCRTStartup+336 (7ffdb000,1bfac8,77b137eb,7ffdb000)
 [24] 0x75e9ed5c KERNEL32.BaseThreadInitThunk+18 (7ffdb000,77a09f0b,0,0)
 [25] 0x77b137eb ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain+239 (10f30d8,7ffdb000,0,0)
 [26] 0x77b137be ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain+194 (10f30d8,7ffdb000,0,0)
```

Comment: That's not an error. It is telling you that the Notes client crashed. You need to open the NSD file created in the data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder. Then look for "FATAL". It will give you the fatal stack. Post that in your question.

Comment: Here is the Dump file that created, the file size very big, but i don't understand what it generate, there have so much word inside

http://www.mediafire.com/view/e9l90mb4zel33eg/nsd_W32I_DESMOND-PC_2013_10_24%4009_02_21.log

Comment: Looks like the issue may be at the crystal reports end. Do you have a (reduced) sample code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: It look like a crviewer9.dll error. But i try on other PC and laptop using window 7 doesn't has any error. Is it some other software driver crash with crystal report, but read on nsd file that produce by lotus notes, it seem only few function call and create the fatal error. For example, "nlnotes" and "crviewer9" .

Comment: Whatever is going on is happening in the crviewer9 at the time of the crash. Notes generates an NSD if it crashes, or anything it is calling  reports an error critical enough to cause possible corruption.  So really need a sample to see what's going on.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It does not belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, maybe it is kind of a programming question since it involves a reporting tool. Kind of a gray area, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PATH environment variable in Windows. And old rule of thumb is to have the Lotus Notes program directory located amongst the first 128 characters of the PATH variable. On my machine I specify my Notes program directory as the first "normal" path after all the Windows-variables like %SystemRoot%\system32 etc.
Finally check that the same goes for the directory in Crystal Reports holding any DLLs like crviewer9.dll.
If that doesn't work, I would use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and run that on crviewer9.dll to see if any obvious DLLs are missing.

EDIT: Just scanning the net for some of the files you mention, seems to suggest that there is problem with the Visual Studio 2010 redistributable package. Look down at the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems).

Comment: for Environment Variable:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
%SystemRoot%\system32;

It already point to my Lotus notes application.


%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;
C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\;
C:\Program Files\IBM\Notes\Data

Comment: After run dependency walker, it say this file is missing.

API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL