# Missing unknown .DLL when attempting to install pyWin32

Tags: python, dll, pywin32

I'm trying to install the pywin32 library for Python 2.6 on a new x64 Windows 7 box.  I'm using the installer from [the Python Extension Packages page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) (pywin32-218.4.win-amd64-py2.6); when I run the installer, it appears to complete, but upon finishing shows the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 613, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 323, in install
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

There is no apparent indication what exactly is missing.  Dependency Walker reports several missing .DLLs

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-COM-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

...but it appears from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems) that these would be expected to be reported missing under normal operation.  I have Visual Studio 2010 installed and have tried installing the MSVC 2008 and 2010 redistributables, to no apparent effect.

Any insight is appreciated, thanks!