# Why do I get an error when trying to install Crystal Reports for VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

This is the error message I get:

> "Error 1904. Module C:\ProgramData\Macrovision\FLEXnet
>      Connect\6\dwusplay.dll failed to register. HRESULT
>      -2147024894. Contact your support personnel."

I think I am installing the right thing, since I downloaded it from this link.

It installs pretty well at first but just before the setup ends, that error message occurs.

It's my first time using Crystal Reports (because I need it for a database project ) so I really don't know how to check that error. Also, I'm still a beginner. I already have Visual Studio 2010 installed. I also tried clicking Ignore when this error happens but this results in Crystal Reports not really installed (it says installed but I can't find it in the Programs list) therefore I can't use it. I tried clicking Retry but the error message still shows (of course). I'm using Windows 7 Starter 64-bit on an Acer laptop. I tried searching about this error on Google but I can't seem to find any solutions for this. What am I missing here? Please guide me.

Comment: I have already added Crystal Reports Viewer to the toolbox. But there should also be a Crystal Reports Document. I have tried looking for it (in the Toolbox, right-click > choose items) but there's only the report viewer. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This Error happened to me when I was installing Crystal Report Run time on Production Server. I have checked the dll dependency using dependency walker and found that few dll are missing. Searched the reason for the missing dll and installed the required package. In my case, installing VC++ Redistributable gave the required dll. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Crystal Report package after that. We can call regsvr32 on the failed to register dlls as well.

Reference : [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

Comment: Thanks, Parveen I had this problem on server 2012 and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The program wont be at Programs list. Go to Visual Studio, right click on your project, add new item and check if you have "Crystal reports" under "Reporting".

Comment: u can try to manually register the .dll. Check this http://scn.sap.com/thread/1122647