# "ImportError: DLL load failed" SciPy and cx_freeze don't work together

Tags: python, windows, dll, scipy, cx-freeze

It seems that `SciPy` and `cx_freeze` don't work together and is a known issue (https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/43/import-errors-when-using-cx_freeze-with). When I remove the `import scipy` then my code runs well.

I have researched here and few other websites and installed Dependency Walker. It says `ieshims.dll` is missing. I have installed `ieshims.dll`. I have installed all other `.dll` files. Now my console window gives me error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyMoss.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 163, in <module>
    from .optimize import *
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .linesearch import (line_search_wolfe1, line_search_wolfe2,
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import minpack2
  File "<loader>", line 10, in <module>
  File "<loader>", line 8, in __load
ImportError: (DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.)  
  'C:\\Python33\\dist\\scipy.optimize.minpack2.pyd'
```

I can see `scipy.optimize.minpack2.pyd` in my build folder but yet generates such error. Please help me out as I am able to run `SciPy` function in Python IDLE while I am unable to run the same function with `cx_freeze` or `py2exe`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't know much about dependency walker, but you might be able to use SciPy by copying the whole `scipy` package folder into the cx_Freeze build directory (where your exe is created), and deleting scipy from library.zip.

Comment: @ThomasK : I did what you have suggested. Now I am getting error as `DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application`. Please help me.

Comment: That error usually means that you're trying to mix 32 bit and 64 bit libraries/executables.

Comment: @ThomasK : I have reinstalled all of my libraries and all are in 64-bit. Now the error changed to the previous one. `scipy_optimize_minpack2.py.....The specified module could not be found`. I have my complete python script running in python IDLE, can you suggest me other installer making program which can make `.exe` files from `.py` files

Comment: Can you show the full error? As for alternatives: my project [pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) makes an installer for your application, though not an exe. If you're on Python 2, there's also [pyinstaller](http://pyinstaller.org/), but that doesn't work if you're on Python 3.

Comment: @ThomasK : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 163, in <module>
    from .optimize import *
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .linesearch import (line_search_wolfe1, line_search_wolfe2,
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\linesearch.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scipy.optimize import minpack2
ImportError: (DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.) 'C:\\Python33\\dist\\scipy.optimize.minpack2.pyd'`

Comment: Can you edit it into your question so it's easier to read. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasK : Edited my question. Can you figure out why am I facing such problem making the installer using `SciPy`.

Comment: That message usually means that it couldn't find some other DLL that that one relies on. You might be able to work it out with dependency walker. This stuff is problematic because none of the tools to make exes from Python are very robust, and it's not something that projects like scipy normally have to deal with.

Comment: @ThomasK : I have installed almost 10 `.dll` files, but everytime I open Dependency Walker, it comes up with name of new `.dll` files. Here is a similar problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems . Is the problem with my computer or with the installer?? If I open the installer(.exe) in another computer will it run smoothly??

Comment: That question appears to indicate that Dependency Walker can give you misleading results. I'm sorry, I don't think I know enough about this to help.