# Crash when using GSL with Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, linker, gsl

I am trying to use `GSL` in Qt/C++. I compiled the library using MinGW in Windows following [this tutorial](http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/redmine/projects/bornagain/wiki/Windows_build?version=41).

I did not copy the directory, `GSL` is in c:/gsl-1.16

I linked in Qt like this:

```
win32{
INCLUDEPATH += C:/gsl-1.16/include /
INCLUDEPATH += C:/gsl-1.16/lib
LIBS += -LC:/gsl-1.16/bin -llibgsl-0 -llibgslcblas-0
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib example.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
}
```

And it recognizes the `#include <gsl/...>`.

But when I use a `GSL` object, the application just crashes at the start but it builds well.

Am I forgetting something or doing something wrong?

Comment: add folder that contains gsl.dll to your environment variable PATH, or copy dll next to your executable. use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out any other missing dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I checked my .exe by using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (Thanks @canberk)

It tells me that some delay-load dll is missing (that's why the build is OK)

those dll are the same as [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

After install [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)
(I install both x86 and x64)

And **restart Qt** and **clean the project**, the problem is solved.