# Dependency Walker: error opening file the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++, dll, dependency-walker

I am trying to find out the dependency of my C++ project. I have both .dll and .so file for that project.

I am trying to use dependency walker to find out the dependency. I think that I have already set up the correct search path. However, it still gives errors:

```
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL: error opening file the system cannot find the file specified
```

and similar error for other files:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
GPSVC.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

I searched for these .dll files and these are not even on my computer. Could someone please help me?

Could someone suggest alternative to dependency walker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

Comment: @RichardCritten Many solutions have been recommended. I tried a couple of those such as installing  Visual studio "redistributable package.". But, these did not help.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @GarimaSingh, any further forward?  I know this is old, I have the same problem.