# TlbImp.exe can't register lib file : ".dll is not a valid type library"

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6

The .dll is FKAttend.dll comes with a VB6.0 SDK of a biometrics device. 
The .dll works fine in VB6.0 environment. However when trying to register it in another PC with VS.NET environment, it is giving the above error.

We inspected the .dll using dependency walker and it shows the following errors. **How can I get this .dll registered and worked in VS.Net environment?**

[image]

Comment: Is FKVIADEV.DLL on the new PC?

Comment: @Rob I guess the [root cause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems) is found here. This is definitely not obvious. But a solution is what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently windows 7 introduced some sort of DLL forwarding that Depends.exe doesn't know about.

[Wikipedia has an article detailing this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker), but doesn't mention why the author no longer updates it.   I suspect the author no longer works for MS.

So those are a red herring, the problem actually lies elsewhere.

See also [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

PS: OpenHub.net has a GNU Dependency walker page, but there is absolutely nothing behind it.  The project link 404s, not one line of code.  Sad!

Comment: I've added a code location to https://www.openhub.net/p/gnudepwalker