# Win7, dependency error in 64bit visual studio

Tags: c++, dll, 32bit-64bit, intel-mkl

I try to build some program using Visaul studio 2013 with 64 bit dll options.

But when I check dependency using dependency walker they told me external dlls are 32bit like below.

[image: Dependecy]

The examples of external libraries are in below:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE ...
API-MS-WIN-CORE ...
API-MS-WIN-CORE ...
...
EXT_MS_WIN ...
...
KERNEL32.DLL
KERNELBASE.DLL
...
```

My question is somehow related with this thread

[Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

But the differences are I have those dlls 32bit.

So I may have to change them to 64 bit.

How could I bring 64 bit external libraries of those?

I already set 64 bit platform in configuration

Comment: Dependency Walker has not been maintained in a very long time.  It just fumbles at these recent Windows innovations.  Don't trust anything it says.