# Qt programs (Canopy GUI, ipython qtconsole) crash in Enthought Canopy Win7 64Bits

Tags: python, qt, pyside, enthought, canopy

I installed Canopy 1.5.2 on Windows 7 - 64 Bits. I performed all steps described on [Enthought web page](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469200-Understanding-a-Canopy-system-wide-installation-common-install-), but Canopy GUI won't to start. I realized that the problem is something related with Qt, because applications that don't need such programs (like Mayavi, Pylab, etc) work perfectly. When I try to run, p.e. `ipython qtconsole`, the following appears on console:

```
D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts>ipython qtconsole
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\qt\console\qtconsolea
pp.py", line 45, in gui_excepthook
    old_excepthook(exctype, value, tb)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86_
64\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86_
64\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\__main__.py", line 14
, in <module>
    start_ipython()
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 12
0, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py
", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py
", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", l
ine 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py
", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py",
 line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", l
ine 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py
", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py
", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py
", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\config\application.py
", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\importstring.py
", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\qt\console\qtconsolea
pp.py", line 50, in <module>
    from IPython.external.qt import QtCore, QtGui
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\qt.py", line
 23, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\qt_loaders.p
y", line 277, in load_qt
    result = loaders[api]()
  File "D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\external\qt_loaders.p
y", line 229, in import_pyside
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg
ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

D:\Enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts>
```

,but when I start `ipython notebook` everything is OK. I also updated all packages using `enpkg`. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I settting `set QT_API = pyqt` and now I'm able to run `ipython qtconsole` and `ipython qtconsole -pylab=qt` . But i still cant run Canopy GUI ( Code Editor or Package Manager).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error means that PySide is either unable to find the Qt DLLs, or the ones it did find are not the right version and do not have some of the expected symbols.  Do you have some other set of Qt libraries on your system in the PATH somewhere?  You can use the Dependency Walker tool to examine the PySide *.pyd files to see what other DLLs it is searching for and the ones it loads.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't have any Qt installation, except the qt package installed using `enpkg`. I followed your advice, and when I check with Dependency Walker Tools for QtCore.pyd, looks like the problem is related with the API-MS-WIN dlls. Based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems) I check my Visual Studio C++ installation and I have already 2013 version. How can I install this dlls? Thanks for your time...