# dll assembly or dependency not found

Tags: c#, dll, windows-runtime, .net-assembly

I have a dll which is used as interface to another application. If I try to use the dll in a program under Windows 7 x64 I got an exception during runtime that the assembly or a dependency of the assembly could not be found.

I used dependency walker which gave me this output: 
[image]

I know this may be a duplicate of [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems) but I was not able to resolve the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Kind regards, Fox

Comment: Dependecy walker works for unmanaged code. You will need to use Fusion Log Viewer to understand what is causing managed assembly load failure

Comment: See [how to enable assembly bind failure logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean Debug and Release folders in your solution. Then remove and add unity again.

Or

1: - Check if you are referencing an assembly which in turn referencing an old version of unity. For example let's say you have an assembly called ServiceLocator.dll which needs an old version of Unity assembly, now when you reference the ServiceLocator you should provide it with the old version of Unity, and that makes the problem.

2: - May be the output folder where all projects build their assemblies, has an old version of unity.

You can use FusLogVw to find out who is loading the old assemblies, just define a path for the log, and run your solution, then check (in FusLogvw) the first line where the Unity assembly is loaded, double click it and see the calling assembly, and here you go.

Answer (score 0):

The failure was on my side.

I had two .dll files in my directory nearly the same name. One was about 6MB the other one only 50KB which seems to be some kind of wrapper. Setting the reference to the 6MB file solved the issue.