# UnsatisfiedLinkError (cannot find dependent libraries)

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

I am writing a program that uses JNI, and it works fine when I run it on my computer, but it throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError if I try to run it on another compupter, saying that it cannot find the dependent libraries. I use Eclipse, and I've tried everything (or a lot of things, whichever you prefer).

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

First, check if you copied all DLL's you use in your project to the target system.
If the error still occurs, it seems that one or more DLL's your JNI-DLL's depending on are missing on the target system.

Download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to your other computer and load the DLL you're using with Dependency Walker. 
It lists all DLL's your DLL is relying on and even shows if a dependency is missing.
If there's something missing, copy the files either from your system or download them.

Comment: Dependency Walker found a bunch of missing dlls, all of them beginning with "API-MS-WIN-" or "EXT-MS-WIN-". Note that I am compiling my project in both 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: Make sure you have installed the same vc++ redistributables on both machines. If the problem still persists, try to collect all dependencies of your project on your machine and copy them to the target. There is a similar problem to yours [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

Comment: I have tested it on a Windows 10 notebook and a Windows 10 VM. They both have the same VC++ redistributables.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, but I have a similar problem. My Javaproject uses JNI too and I'm using NetBeans for development. After upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10, my project won't run in Netbeans anymore. Running my project outside of NetBeans from command line, even though Dependency Walker can't find API-MS-WIN and EXT-MS-WIN DLL's. [Here's my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746561/unsatisfiedlinkerror-in-netbeans-when-calling-native-dll-after-windows-10-upgrad), if you've found a solution, please let me know, maybe it's helpful for me, too.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 as well. I'm not sure if this started happening on my computer when I updated to Windows 10 though.