# UnsatisfiedLinkError in Netbeans when calling native DLL after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: java, netbeans, java-native-interface

After upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10, my Netbeans Project throws UnsatisfiedLinkErrors when calling native DLL's:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\SVN\SoftwareProjectsV2\Modules\PTS\trunk\SimController_JNIWrapper.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Running my Java-Program outside of Netbeans works just fine, only Netbeans seems to have a problem finding the DLL's.

I already added -Djava.library.path= to the VM Options without improvement.

Has somebody experienced something similar and could give me a hint?

Comment: _"Can't find dependent libraries"_ you may need to reinstall some dependent libraries (eg the MSVC libs, or something like that)

Comment: Already done that. Besides my jar runs perfectly when I run it from command line

Comment: Ah, missed that part. Weird, it would suggest that Netbeans uses a different path then normal applications.

Comment: No problem. It's really weird, also removed Netbeans with all components and user-files and reinstalled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a clean reinstall of Windows 10, Java, MSVC libs, Netbeans and creating a new project from my source files and DLL's, I still can't run my project from NetBeans.

Tested my project with Eclipse and it works, so I'm switching to Eclipse with all my projects.

Not the solution I had in mind, but at least I can work again.

---

After adding my projects rootfolder, which contains my dll's, to the PATH environment variable, I can use NetBeans again. But this is also not the ideal solution, since I have different projects, using different versions of the same dll.