# Missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-0.dll when launching Delphi IDE

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

[image]

This message appears when I launch Delphi 2009 Enterprise. I installed Windows Updates today (Windows 7 Professional) and updated TortoiseSVN to 1.9.

An [article](https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0dll-is-missing-f2702.html) related to a FTP server points to a required installation of Visual Studio 2015 redistributables.

Also related: [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

Did anybody experience the same and found a fix?

Installed experts:
* GExperts
* IDEFixpack 
* DDevextensions

Comment: If the article you found points to a required installation of Visual Studio **2015** redistributables, then clearly installation of Visual Studio **2013** files won't fix the problem. The numbers are important; read them  again.

Comment: Could it be that you installed TortoiseSVN 1.9 ? After I did that today, I got the same error message. But by reading the "Missing DLLs" section on the TortoiseSVN download page I know that I needed to download yet another Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen yes, I also installed TortoiseSVN 1.9 on the same day, thank you for sharing. I will try to reproduce it on other systems and install the VS 2015 redistributable files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have installed the new TortoiseSVN 1.9 then it may be the cause. It requires the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145). This is mentioned on the [Tortoise 1.9 download page](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html) under *Missing DLLs*.

Here is a [discussion](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3131378) on the TortoiseSVN discussion forum.