# System.IO.FileNotFoundException after start of application

Tags: c#, dll

I try to run the CSdump .NET example from the Kvaser SDK. Download under following link:
https://www.kvaser.com/developer/

After default installation the example is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Kvaser\Canlib\Samples\NET\vs2010\CSdump

I try to build and run the example for x86 CPU because later on I want to use a Kvaser interface in a x86 application. I adjusted my project Properties and CPU Type to x86. I checked it under

I copied the canlibCLSNET.dll into the CSdump directory and added the DLL to the project references. When I executed the Code Analysis of Visual Studio I got a complain that a reference to Microsoft.VisualC 7.0.5000.0 is missing. I added a reference to Microsoft.VisualC 10.0. All Microsoft redistributeable packages from VS 2008 to VS 2015 are installed for x86 and x64.

I tried to use dependency walker and it yields the same errors like described here: [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems) but I could not resolve my issue with the advices there.

I don't know what to try else, any recommondations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem when I used the canlibCLSNET.dll from the location C:\Program Files (x86)\Kvaser\Canlib\dotnet\win32\fw11\canlibCLSNET.dll.

I fixed it by referencing a different version of the canlibCLSNET.dll that was suitable for my system. I used the one under C:\Program Files (x86)\Kvaser\Canlib\dotnet\x64\fw40\canlibCLSNET.dll

There is a document here that explains which version to use for which system https://www.kvaser.com/developer-blog/setting-up-canlib-for-visual-studio/