# Can't load DLL after Windows 10 March update

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-10, dllnotfoundexception

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so I am open to suggestions.

I have been working on a C++/C# school project for the past few months on Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. The project is a robot simulator and we use a dll named Noyau.dll that was created for us by the teacher and lab assistants. We use P/Invoke between C# and C++ to access the libraries.

Never had a problem with Visual Studio until this last Sunday (March 13th). My computer started an update for Windows 10 and now when I try to run my program it says:

> First-chance exception at 0x00007FF93DFC1F28 in InterfaceGraphique.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: EEMessageException at memory location 0x00000043C3DFE360.
>
> A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in InterfaceGraphique.exe
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in InterfaceGraphique.exe
>   Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'Noyau.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

The only thing that happened in between when it was working and when it stopped working is the Windows 10 Update. "Noyau.dll" is compiled and it is in the right directory. The project works for my whole team. It works on my desktop computer. The project is much probably fine, my laptop seems to be the problem.

So of course, I searched for similar problems and many people suggest the use of Dependency Walker which I did. When I run "Noyau.dll" with Dependency Walker, I get that tons of dlls seem to be missing but I have no idea what these are. They seem to be core dlls. I could go and start downloading them all separately, but there are hundreds of them.

What I have tried so far:

- I ran the repair tool for Visual Studio
- I reinstalled Visual Studio 2013
- I downloaded Visual C++ redistributable packages for visual studio 2013 x64
- I ran Dependency Walker (I posted a link to a screenshot at the end of the post)

My computer is a Dell XPS13 9343 running Windows 10 Home x64.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCP80.jpg) of Dependency Walker.

I am sorry if this looks like a duplicate, but I have never seen a Windows Update break my Visual Studio or my dlls.

---

EDIT: Ok, I ran Dependency Walker on my .exe instead. I found that many dlls are missing in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\`

> LoadLibraryExW("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\VERSION.dll", 0x0000000000000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).

I can't find these ones in the specified path but I can find them in System32:

- VERSION.dll
- ole32.dll

Why can't Dependency Walker find these two dlls?

---

FINALLY:

This is an old thread, but if anyone comes across this in the future I had to reset my laptop and reinstall VS to fix it. If anyone ever comes across this problem and finds a better solution, feel free to leave an answer here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems)

Comment: I have tried downloading the redistributable packages but it didn't solve my problem. Your link suggests that Dependency Walker is misleading (which I was suspecting because all of a sudden all those dlls went missing).

Comment: Try running Dependency Walker on your desktop computer and compare the results.

Comment: Two things you can try; 1. compile your c# project as `x86` instead of `any cpu`. 2. run `regsvr32 path\to\Noyau.dll`. If you get an errormessage saying `Noyau.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found`, the dll can be loaded fine, and it's dependencies are not the problem.

Comment: _I downloaded Visual C++ redistributable packages for visual studio 2013 x64_, [also](http://superuser.com/q/695704) install the x86 version on x64 pc's

Comment: @Wimmel 1. Compiling as `x86` didn't do it. 2. Running `regsvr32` fails to load `Noyau.dll`. 3. I downloaded both. Still didn't work.
Ugh... My computer really doesn't want to use my dll anymore.

Comment: @Richard I just saw your comment about trying `dependency walker` on my desktop! I will try it tonight and and post the results if anything is suspicious.

Comment: I have exactly same problem and after reading your post, it seems to me that the cause might be due to conflict between multiple visual studios or multiple redistributable packages. You might not have the problem in Windows 7, but Windows 10 did something to break the environment.