# gRPC + SSL = UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: ssl, openssl, grpc

I've been trying to SSL-ify my gRPC service (which works fine in plaintext mode).  Note: this is in a commercial context which limits some of my options (such as development environment & deployment platform).

I followed [SECURITY.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md) which recommends using OpenSSL ... and therefore [netty-tcnative](https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative) ... which leads to [Forked Tomcat Native](http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html) and a number of choices:

1. `netty-tcnative-{arch}` - dynamically linked, requires APR and OpenSSL already installed on target systems
2. `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-{os_arch}` - statically linked to APR and google's OpenSSL fork
3. `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` - statically linked uber jar with native libraries for common platforms
4. `netty-tcnative-openssl-static-{os_arch}` - statically linked to APR and OpenSSL ... but isn't on maven central so not my first choice

## #3

The doc says #3 is the simplest artifact to use.
But, for me, that results in a failure to find netty-tcnative.dll (which, in this case, should come from the jar AFAIK).

## #2

This looks to be the next simplest.
Supposedly I can use [os-maven-plugin](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin) to figure out, at build time, the classifier to use for the versions of these artifacts that require one (i.e. 2 and 4).
Although it correctly works them out (according to `mvn compile` output), I get different runtime behaviour:

- using `<classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>` I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL`
- hard-coding to `<classifier>windows-x86_64</classifier>` I get further but still no cigar: now netty-tcnative won't load: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Temp\netty-tcnative1392766600896877072.dll: Can't find dependent libraries` (an unusual path because the DLL's been copied from the jar to my temp directory and `System.load`'ed from there)

  - According to [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), that DLL has a whole stack of dependencies some of which really don't appear on my filesystem.  But it seems that's because [depends.exe hasn't kept up with the times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems).
  - The same code also doesn't work on a colleague's PC so it's not just me.
  - And I still have a problem because my target system is RHEL, not Windows (my kingdom for a Linux workstation!).  So I'd have to figure out how to fix the `${os.detected.filesystem}` problem...

## #4

This might work I guess.  But it's not on maven central so is not my favoured path.

## #1

Probably would work.  But means installing APR and OpenSSL on whichever servers we deploy upon.  I don't like my chances of that for internal PaaS I have to use.  Avoid for now.

## TLS with JDK

I *might* try this.
But [the doc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md) strongly recommends against it as you have to fiddle with Java's bootclasspath (I can imagine more PaaS obstacles here, perhaps unfounded...).
And it's apparently not overly performant (>10x slower than OpenSSL).
And it's brittle (Jetty-ALPN version must correspond exactly with JRE in use although it sounds like there may be solutions to this).

## The bottom line

If I can't solve this problem, it may kill gRPC for my project.  Whether or not that's a bad thing is up for debate...  In the meantime, does anyone have any ideas or a working SSL-ified gRPC client/server app ([grpc-java/examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples) all use plaintext only).

Comment: For #3, you have to use at least grpc-java-0.14.0 to pull in a new enough Netty. Also, you need to use at least 1.1.33.Fork16 of tcnative. That said, you'd still encounter the same issue as for #2. We're looking into what's wrong with #2.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using 1.1.33.Fork16 (was on Fork15 before) but, as you say, I'm still getting the same issue.  But it looks like @nmittler is working on that :-)

Comment: FWIW I also switched to grpc-java-0.14.0 (from 0.13.2) to re-try #3 but got IllegalArgumentException (but stepping through the code it looks to have the same root cause as #2's failure: cannot load dependent libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a netty-tcnative bug.  I've just created https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/141 and will be looking at reducing the list of dependencies brought in by MSVC.

For now, try building openssl[static/dynamic] yourself and see if that works for you.

Comment: I see you've released 1.1.33.Fork17 which does indeed fix my problem.  Thanks very much!

Comment: ... although I now have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395579/grpc-ssl-uber-jar-linux-failed-to-load-netty-tcnative