# gRPC + SSL + uber jar + Linux = Failed to load netty-tcnative

Tags: linux, ssl, grpc

Thanks to @nmittler on [gRPC + SSL = UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297462/grpc-ssl-unsatisfiedlinkerror) I've got gRPC + SSL working on my Windows PC and on the target Linux platform.

But only when I specify a `<classifier>` for the `io.netty/netty-tcnative-boringssl-static/1.1.33.Fork17` dependency.  That can be:

1. hard-coded (e.g. to `windows-x86_64`)
2. injected using [os-maven-plugin](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin) and `${os.detected.classifier}`

But that means I can only run on:

1. Windows (or whichever platform I hard-code)
2. the platform I used to compile

But what I'd *really* like to be able to do is compile on Windows but run on Linux.  So, *in theory*, I can just leave off the `<classifier>` to bring in the uber-jar (as specified in [the docs](http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html)).

But this doesn't work: when I step through `io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load()` I find a call to `System.mapLibraryName()`.

- On Windows this correctly returns `netty-tcnative.dll`.
- But on Linux (RHEL 7) it returns `libnetty-tcnative.so` ... which isn't in the uber-jar (`jar tf netty-tcnative-boringssl-static-1.1.33.Fork17.jar` returns, among others, `META-INF/native/libnetty-tcnative-linux-x86_64.so`).

Looking at the *classified* linux version of the jar I can see it contains `META-INF/native/libnetty-tcnative.so` ... which implies either the uber jar needs to be built differently (to rename `libnetty-tcnative-linux-x86_64.so` to `libnetty-tcnative.so`) or `NativeLibraryLoader` somewhere needs to take account of the different naming...

Am I on the right track?  Can someone help fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to `io.grpc/grpc-all/0.14.0` (from `0.13.2`) cured my problem because it brings in a newer version of `io.netty/netty-handler` (`4.1.0.CR7` vs. `4.1.0.CR3`).

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the uber jar on Maven Central does not contain the shared libraries. It's not yet clear whether the issue is building or deploying the jar. I've raised https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/145 to track the fix.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've added my 2p-worth to that issue.

Comment: Discussed offline. The uber jar on Maven is fine. It seems that the problem was that you were using an old version of Netty (4.1.0-CR3) which didn't support the uber jar.  Uber jar support was introduced in 4.1.0-CR4 and upgrading seems to have resolved your issue.