# Limit to size of array type, while there's not yet an instance

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, visual-c++, size

I have the following minimal test program:

```
struct Test { 
    double contents [1000000000];
};

int main () {
    return 0;
}
```

It refuses to compile, even though the compiler cannot know wether I will instantiate Test statically, on the stack or on the heap.
Why does the compiler complain?
Are objects on the heap also restricted to 2GB?

Compilation error report: test.cpp(2): error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes

Platform: Windows 10 64 bit, 16GB RAM

Compiler: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27027.1 for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Comment: Are you compiling for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I've used cl -help to find out if there's a switch for that, but it wasn't listed. I have no Visual Studio, only the command line compiler. Since I am on 64 bit, I assumed 64 bit compilation.

Comment: If using shared memory, allocate it with your shared memory allocator and just use a `double* ` no need for an array.  The shared memory will give you the raw memory.

Comment: [How to compile x64 code with Visual Studio in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548138/how-to-compile-x64-code-with-visual-studio-in-command-line)

Comment: Btw. Very similar error is emitted on `gcc`, when forced to compile in 32-bit mode: https://wandbox.org/permlink/CXGLaXvnscnZPOFu  (in default mode it compiles fine). 32-bit C++ programs have hard limit of 2GB memory, so I suppose program with structure that could exceed that amount is ill-formed. I don't have any stadard to confirm that tho.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I've followed the link, and it turns out I am indeed using the 64 bit compiler at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe. BTW if I use a typedef rather than a struct it behaves just the same.

Comment: @RichardCritten The problem is that I want the whole struct in shared memory, not only the array. This is because my struct contains metadata, namely the dimensions of the array (which is actually multi-dimensional, but I simplified not to bother people with lots of code.) I want any process having access to the shared memory to be able to read the metadata. Of course I can share that via a side channel, but that seems less elegant.

Comment: "Are objects on the heap also restricted to 2GB?" No, but you may have problem in allocation, if you  had fragmentation in memory

Comment: I never used MSVC personally, so I connot help further if that question doesn't help. As far as I understand, to compile 64bit program in MSVC, you need a separate compiler, located somewhere else. This should solve the problem of too big structure, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach to tackle your problem.

Comment: @oblivion Indeed fragmentation may prohibit allocation, but the compiler didn't even give me a chance to TRY to allocate :(

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Error: Total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173040/error-total-size-of-array-must-not-exceed-0x7fffffff-bytes)

Comment: It is interesting that 32 bit compiler cares about the stack size you may need, and 64 bit doesn't https://godbolt.org/z/o0N9oc. each instance of `Test` needs about 8Mb which won't fit in stack memory which is allocated at program start up.

Comment: The limit of array sizes is implementation defined. The C++ language recommended minimum for the size of an array is 262,144.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of MSVC.  I tried compiling your code with both the 32 bit (x86) and 64 bit (x64) compilers and got the same result (tested with compiler version 19.13.26132, MSVC 2017).

Comment: Clang also refuses to compile it.

Comment: A compiler is allowed to limit the size of an object it supports. See [\[implimits\] 2.17](http://eel.is/c++draft/implimits#2.17): *"Size of an object ([\[intro.object\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object)) \[262 144\]."*