# Python traits.api DLL files missing

Tags: python, windows

I installed traitsui 5.1.0 with pip behalf of Python(x,y) with the purpose to load the python module `traits.api` but there is an error appearing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import traits.api
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\api.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .trait_base import Uninitialized, Undefined, Missing, Self, python_version
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\traits\trait_base.py", line 135, in <module>
    from . import ctraits
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I found a similar question but unanswered on google: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/OgJDjH-nlQo

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) detects missing files:

```
MSVCR90.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
GPSVC.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

So I checked their availability: [Win 7, 64 bit, dll problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17023419/2062965). But they are available on my machine (MS Web Tools and SDKs)! Do I need to copy them? Thanks for giving me an idea.

Comment: Dependency Walker doesn't work correctly with activation contexts, so it incorrectly thinks some DLLs are missing. Anyway, the `ImportError` is complaining about a missing procedure in a DLL, not a missing DLL.

Comment: I just tested in Windows 10 via `pip install traitsui` (specifically `py -2 -m pip install traitsui` since my `pip` is Python 3). It worked fine for me. The ctraits.pyd extension depends on msvcr90.dll and python27.dll, the same as python.exe, so I don't readily see how that could be a problem -- but then I don't use the Python(x,y) distro, which could be weird in some way. It's probably a bad build that's not exporting the required Python 2.x initialization procedure `initctraits`.

Comment: @eryksun: I just have Python 2 only (on Win7 64bit).