# Unable to load DLL 'oasoa.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, openaccess

I installed the OpenAccess server sdk,Then compiled the sample code oanet.csproj,when I tried to run this project's .exe file, at the run time it shows the error " 0x8007007E", so I came to know that oasoa.dll's dependencies are missing , so with the help of DEPENDENCY WALKER tool I found that, there are number of dependencies are missing as shown in snap below,                            [image]

Now the problem is that the count of the oasoa.dll dependency files is so much huge,still I downloaded many of them and try to reduced the problem, but I was unable to find all of them with specific version, I have also installed all C++ redistributable packages properly, so what should I do now?? please help.

Comment: You can try checking out http://stackoverflow.com/a/20606198/6138713

Comment: I had this problem when I didn't install the *right* visual-c runtime. Double-check what runtime is required and what you have installed