# 0xc00007b error on running exe made by csharp

Tags: c#, .net

I have some problems with dot net framework;

I've just installed Visual-Studio on my Windows 7 PC but when i make an empty program with C# and .Net 2 to 4 ;I get 0xc000007b error; So, I googled and found out that dependency walker could help in these situations and I downloaded It and It shows me that I haven't these dlls:

```
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
MSS32.DLL
```

I don't know where to download them or for which libraries are them.

Comment: Dependency Walker is old and doesn't work with the new Windows runtime libraries. I don't think it's useful anymore.

Comment: But what DLLs specifically? I just see an empty white image. Can you post the names as text please?

Comment: @Rup added names

Comment: @Rup So what is an update alternative?

Comment: The API* and ieshims should be under C:\Windows\WinSxS, where dependency walker wouldn't find them. dcomp.dll should be under c:\windows\system32, where it should find it. And I don't recognise mss32.dll -  I don't have that on this laptop. So maybe that's the problem - that's missing?

Comment: Can you run .NET binaries built elsewhere? Is your .NET runtime broken?

Comment: Actually, it's possible that you don't have the api-* DLLs - I think they were only introduced in a later Windows 7 service pack. Do you have the latest service pack? Is the version of .NET that you've installed compatible with your windows and service pack version?

Comment: @Rup I have this problem with some exes since I changed my Windows

Comment: [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17023419/243245) which says that dcomp isn't available on Windows 7. So I guess the problem is Windows 7 then - can you find an older version of .NET that is compatible with 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the Dependency Walker just shows that API* is not available and it can't detect it.

So i googled again and found out that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28304716/13393053) tool is working so better.

I just haven't mscoree.dll.

Comment: mscoree is the "Microsoft .NET Runtime Execution Engine". I'd expect it would come with the framework but maybe it's another one that's bundled with Windows nowadays not the framework itself.